# Did FPE accept subgroups that were NOT geographically compact?

Tags: enders-game

Hegemon Peter Wiggin was (justifiably) proud in that 100% of nations/people that joined Free People of Earth (FPE) did so without any force by FPE, and only after a plebescit to vote in the joining.

One of the big innovations that FPE had was that a minority "splinter group" inside of an existing country could vote to join FPE and be allowed to even if majority of the rest of the country did NOT want to join (e.g. natives in Peru, or non-Muslims in South Sudan as we saw in *Shadow of the Giant*).

But both of these examples were pretty much "mini-countries" in a sense of them having specific territory.

But would/could/did FPE accept as members the minority groups that had no territory they could call their own (e.g. Gypsies/Roma)?

Comment: It's fine if the question is answered by some information directly from Card, not necessarily a book quote. I couldn't find any evidence in Shadow books to lean either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FPE carved out territory for these groups when asked. A transient population like the Roma would have to petition for a home land to be a self governing body, otherwise they would be subject to the laws of the lands they were passing through, including a right to free travel, vote, and the other basic human rights guaranteed by the constitution of the FPE. This mainly taken from the letter at the start of chapter nine.

One other point, not to be taken likely, is that if you lacked enough of a nation to raise an army of some kind, Peter Wiggin didn't consider you his problem. Basically, he was looking to subdue the world and build a lasting government, and some peoples surely fell through the cracks because they lacked enough juice to be worth the squeeze. He built his FPE on social justice because it was the most stable way open to him. Had it been more stable to create a hereditary ruling class after conquering the world, he would have done that.